# Add IP programmatically to ipv4 and domain restriction

Tags: vb.net, iis-7, windows-server-2008, appcmd

Anybody know how to programmatically add an IP address to "IPv4 and domain restrictions" in IIS7 using vb.net.

i.e I want to exclude some ips or range of IPs from accessing certain folders on my server and allow certain users to access it.

I found those nice articles :

http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/ipsecurity/add

https://serverfault.com/questions/305681/iis-7-address-restrictions-importing-list-to-block-china-and-korea-ips

http://www.tuicool.com/articles/uQru6v

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can add the restrictions by executing some command line tool.

*(The following information is copy-pasted from Microsoft IIS documentation)*
**Configure IPv4 Address and Domain Name Allow Rules (IIS 7)** ([Original document here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731598%28v=ws.10%29.aspx))

> To create an allow rule for IPv4 address and domain restriction, use
>   the following syntax:

```
appcmd set config /section:ipsecurity /+"[ipaddress=' string ',allowed='true',subnetMask=' string ',domainName=' string ']"
```

> The variable ipaddress string is a single IPv4 address. The variable
>   subnetMask string is a subnet mask. Use the subnet mask in combination
>   with the IPv4 address to identify an address space that applies to
>   this rule. The variable domain name string is a domain name. Typically
>   you would use an IP address or a domain name, but not both in the same
>   rule.
>
> For example, to create an allow rule for IPv4 address 10.0.0.1, type
>   the following at the command prompt, and then press ENTER:

```
appcmd set config /section:ipsecurity /+"[ipaddress='10.0.0.1',allowed='true']"
```

> For more information about Appcmd.exe, see [Appcmd.exe (IIS 7).](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772200%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

**Update**
For executing the command, you can use a code like the following

```
Sub MySubName
    Process.Start("C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd set config yada-yada-yada...")
End Sub
```

I've never used the **appcmd** command line tool, so you'll need to look at the documentation, and understand how to use it.